# getElementById vs getElementByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm using both `getElementById` and `getElementByClassName`. `getElementById` sometimes returns `null` while `getElementByClassName` works properly every time. What could be the reason for this? I understand that `getElementbyClassName` returns a list, does that mean that the list inside is empty but not the parent itelf?

```
<span
    v-for="(item, ind) in cues"
    :key="ind"
    :class="item.activeclass"
    :id="item.activeclass"
>{{ item.text }}</span>
```

Sometimes the `id` is returned correctly as `[object HTMLSpanElement]` and sometimes it's `null`.
While the `class` always returns `[object HTMLCollection]`

Also, I'm trying to use the `id` inside `scrollIntoView` and it works fine when it's not `null`. Is there a ways to use the `class` in `scrollIntoView` ?

Comment: "does that mean that the list inside is empty"....potentially. Obviously since we can't see your specific code, or run your code or see what objects actually exist in the DOM when you run it, it's hard to tell. But yes getElementByClassName will never return null, if nothing matches you'll just get an empty list. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: element vs a Live HTML Collection.... Means you are referencing elements before they exist on the page.

Comment: There is no such things as `getElementByClassName`

Comment: I think you’re running into a race condition: you might have to wait for next tick before trying to retrieve the DOM node. `getElementById` only return a single node, so it will always be null or the element that’s found. On the other hand `getElementsByClassName` always returns a collection, but the collection is probably empty sometimes if you inspect it.

Answer (score 1):

**getElementsByClassName** returns a list of all elements matching the class name criteria.

If no element exists, then the result will be an empty list.

**getElementById** returns the first element that matches the specified 'id'.
If no element exists, then the result will be 'null'.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't return null if it exists on the page. You're probably not looking it up by the right id.

Based on your code, it looks like you could have more than one of the same id. That's not valid HTML and it's possible that some JavaScript implementations may require a unique id, so you should also make sure all the ids on your page are unique.

As for scrollIntoView, you can just get the id from the element you retrieved when looking it up by class and retrieve `scrollIntoView(spanElement.id)`